# iOS: How do I keep the UIToolbar (that I've added to UIWebView.scrollView) from going off screen?

Tags: ios, uiwebview, safari, uitoolbar

Hopefully i can explain this clearly. I have a UIWebView and I've added a UIToolbar to it's scrollView (another works `[webView.scrollView addSubview:myToolbar];`). So everything is fine and dandy until i try to pinch zoom that's when the toolbar stays in the corner of the screen, so basically it doesn't stay in the middle. If you haven't guessed already, I'm trying to make a duplicate of safari's behavior. I need to have the UIToolbar to not be affected by the pinch gesture. Any ideas on how to do this? I've read other posts but it doesn't seem to really give an answer. Any help is appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a parent UIView, say `rootV`, in which you embed `myToolbar` at the top, and then `webView`.

This stops the pinching from affecting `myToolbar`, however this make it stick at the top, and not move beyond the screen when the user scrolls vertically `myWebView`.

To get the same behavior as Safari, you have to check the vertical scrolling in `myWebView`, and based on it you expand up or down the size of `rootV`. Assuming you fixed the height of `myToolbar` but made `webView` fill the rest, it should just work.

Comment: Ya i have tried that...and currently that's what i'm sticking with until i can put some more time into figuring it out. Thank You :)